# Laravel 5.5: how to stop redirect to previous page after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am using Laravel default authentication
When user loges in I redirect him/her to /dashboard instead of /home

changing this line in RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
return redirect('/home);`
```

to

```
return redirect('/dashboard');
```

now the if user hits another url that requires authentication lets say /abc it will redirect user to login but as soon as he/she gets login it takes user to /abc instead of /dashboard
(As per my requirement)I want it to always take user to /dashboard whenever he/she loges in irrespective of previous page he/she was trying to hit

Anybody got any idea which function is to be overwritten or anything...

Comment: Using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 5):

Intended url is saved in the session. So if we remove the value from the session, user will be redirected to the default route always.

In the `EventServiceProvider`, add an listener for user login event.

ex:

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
     'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
],
```

Now that you added the event, artisan can create the listener with `php artisan event:generate` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#generating-events-and-listeners). In the handle method of the created App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin file, unset the session value `url.intended` as below:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
   session()->remove('url.intended');
}
```

Comment: Why not avoid saving in the session in the first place instead of removing it?

Comment: @thefallen, yes it is possible. However, with the approach suggested by me, you can conditionally manage the feature.

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana this works but now it always redirects to home when first trying to login
After I am logged In and I try to hit login it do redirects me to dashboard but not when I actually provides the credentials

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices, both of them work equally well. Option one:

Open `app/Http/Exception/Handler.php` and override the `unauthenticated()` method like this:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect(route('auth.login'));
}
```

This way you wont be saving in the session the previous URL of the user.

Option 2:

Open your `LoginController` and override the `sendLoginResponse()` method like this:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This way you'll always be redirecting to the redirect path declared in the controller when the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following logic in combination with a `middleware` to redirect any guests trying to hit an ***admin*** protected route to `/login`. After submitting the login form and successful authentication back in the `Auth\LoginController` check if the `session()->has('going_to')` set. If so, use it to redirect to where it points to instead of the default (`/` in my case). Finally hitting the `RedirectIfAdministrator@handle` method again as authenticated user, this time it checks for the admin role and lets the user trough or redirects `back()`.

First figure out *exactly* what you are trying to accomplish and toy around with it a bit. Looking back at what I've wrote, that last `return redirect()->back();` seems odd! At this point `back()` should be pointing to `/login` which is accessible only as guest but then the **Laravel's** `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware kicks in and saves the day!

Most likely there is way more elegant solution to it. Maybe something with the `Redirect::intended($default)->getTargetUrl();` or something.

Anyway hope that helps you..

..in `class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`

```
/**
 * Where to redirect the authenticated user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (session()->has('going_to')) {
        return session()->pull('going_to');
    }

    return '/';
}
```

.. and the handle method of my `class RedirectIfAdministrator`

```
class RedirectIfAdministrator
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Closure                 $next
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->guest()) {
        session(['going_to' => $request->path()]);

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if (auth()->user()->role == config('oxygen.roles.Administrator', 'admin')) {
        return $next($request);
    };

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

Comment: [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users) @ `master` says **:** The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `authenticated` method in your `LoginController`.

```
public function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    return redirect(session()->pull('from', $this->redirectTo));
}
```